# Perform operation on corresponding matching grouped Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe:

`User    Numbers
 A        0
 A        4
 A        5
 B        0
 B        0
 C        1
 C        3`

I want to perform an operation on each corresponding grouped data. For example, if I want to remove all `Users` that have the `Number` 0, it should look like:

`User    Numbers
 A        0
 A        4
 A        5
 C        1
 C        3`

since all `Numbers` of `User` B is 0.

Or for example, if I want to find the variance of the Numbers of all the Users, it should look like:

`Users    Variance
 A          7
 B          0
 C          2`

This means only the `Numbers` of A are calculated for finding the variance of A and so on.

Is there a general way to do all these computations for matching grouped data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 2 different operations - [filtration per groups](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) and [aggregation per groups](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).

**Filtration**:

For better performance is better use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
df1 = df[~df['Number'].eq(0).groupby(df['User']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
  User  Number
0    A       0
1    A       4
2    A       5
5    C       1
6    C       3
```

Steps:

1.First create boolean Series by comparing `Number` by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
print (df['Number'].eq(0))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Number, dtype: bool
```

2.Then use [syntactic sugar](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) - `groupby` by another column and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) function [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) for check if all `True`s per group and `transform` is for mask with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df['Number'].eq(0).groupby(df['User']).transform('all'))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Number, dtype: bool
```

3.Invert boolen mask by `~`:

```
print (~df['Number'].eq(0).groupby(df['User']).transform('all'))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: Number, dtype: bool
```

4.Filter:

```
print (df[~df['Number'].eq(0).groupby(df['User']).transform('all')])
  User  Number
0    A       0
1    A       4
2    A       5
5    C       1
6    C       3
```

Another slowier solution in large DataFrame with [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) and same logic as first solution:

```
df2 = df.groupby('User').filter(lambda x: ~x['Number'].eq(0).all())
print (df2)
  User  Number
0    A       0
1    A       4
2    A       5
5    C       1
6    C       3
```

**Aggregation**:

For simplier aggregation by one column with one aggregate function, e.g. [`GroupBy.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.var.html) use:

```
df3 = df.groupby('User', as_index=False)['Number'].var()
print (df3)
  User  Number
0    A       7
1    B       0
2    C       2
```

Comment: Edited the question as I accidentally pressed submit without completing the question. Is `.all()` used for doing computation over matched grouped data?

Comment: @panaceanoob - Give me some time, I add explanation.